# Get original value of detached entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an API built using ASP.NET CORE. after it gets data to client applications (JS web Applications) like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Article> GetAvaliableArticles()
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    return Entities.Where(s => s.IsAvailable).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder);
}
```

When the client application wants to update each article I attach the entity back to the context:

```
Context.Attach(entity);
if(entity.GetType().GetProperty("ConcurrencyStamp") != null) 
{
    var propertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperty("ConcurrencyStamp");
    propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
Context.Update(entity);
await Context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

However, when I try to audit the change in EF it is not getting the previous value of Article. The original and New values are the same.

```
switch (entry.State) 
{
    case EntityState.Added:
        auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
        break;
    case EntityState.Deleted:
        auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
        break;
    case EntityState.Modified:
        if (property.IsModified) 
        {
            auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
            auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
        }
        break;
}
```

I want `property.OriginalValue` to be the previous value before update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Context.Attach(entity);`, the default or original value are coming from the `entity` which you passed from client side instead of querying database.

For a workaround, you could try `entry.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(property.Metadata.Name)` to get the database original value.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => !(e.Entity is Audit) && e.State != EntityState.Detached && e.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        switch (entry.State)
        {                    
            case EntityState.Modified:
                foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
                {
                    if (property.IsModified)
                    {
                        var original = entry.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(property.Metadata.Name);
                        var current = property.CurrentValue;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```